# Qsort не работает в XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, qsort

Столкнулся с проблемой при решении задачи на XCode.

При использовании `qsort` программа выдает ошибку:

> No matching function for call to 'qsort'

P.S.  накидал заголовочных файлов, но ни с чем не проходит.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <search.h>


using namespace std;

int cmp(int *a, const char *b)  {
return *(float*)a- *(float*)b;
}

int main(int argс ,  const char * argv[]) {

ifstream fin;
fin.open("books.dat");
if (!fin.is_open()) {
    cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
    system("pause");
}

else  {

    float L;

    int N , sum=0;

    int i,j;

    fin >> L;

    fin >> N;

    float* mass_books=new float [N];

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        fin>> mass_books[i];

    fin.close();

     qsort( mass_books, sizeof(float), N, cmp ) ;

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        sum = sum + mass_books[j];

    for (i = N - 1; sum > L; i--)
        sum = sum - mass_books[i];

    cout << "Максимальное количество книг на полке: " <<i + 1 << endl;

    system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: А зачем вам в С++ `qsort`? Есть же `sort`.

Comment: его тоже пробовал, но нет

Answer (score 0):

Написал вместо кьюсорта пузырьковую сортировку, но ответ на вопрос все равно интересно услышать .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <search.h>


using namespace std;

int cmp(int *a, const char *b)  {
return *(float*)a- *(float*)b;
}

int main(int argс ,  const char * argv[]) {

ifstream fin;
fin.open("books.dat");
if (!fin.is_open()) {
    cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
    system("pause");
}

else  {

    float L;

    int N , sum=0;

    int i,j;

    float prom;

    fin >> L;

    fin >> N;

    float* mass_books=new float [N];

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        fin>> mass_books[i];

    fin.close();

    //qsort( mass_books, sizeof(float), N, cmp ) ; у меня не проходит       эта функция

    //напишем пузырьковую сортировку 


    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N-1;j++)
        {
            if (mass_books[j]>mass_books[j+1])
            {
                prom = mass_books[j+1];
                mass_books[j+1] = mass_books[j] ;
                mass_books[j] = prom;
             }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        cout<<mass_books[i]<<endl;





    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        sum = sum + mass_books[j];

    for (i = N - 1; sum > L; i--)
        sum = sum - mass_books[i];

    cout << "Максимальное количество книг на полке: " <<i + 1 << endl;

    system("pause");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> P.S. накидал заголовочных файлов, но ни с чем не проходит.

Это называется "вуду-программирование". Основная идея в том чтобы случайным образом "накидывать" разные команды. Если уж вы решили его использовать, попробуйте и другие популярные приемы этой парадигмы:

- Добавить 1
- Вычесть 1
- Закоментить некоторые строки
- Заключить весь код в `try` `catch` блоки
- Многое другое

**P.S.** Но я бы просто зашел на сайт типа cplusplus.com или cppreference.com, а то и просто в гугл и посмотрел в каких именно библиотеках находятся функции [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) и [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort)

**P.P.S.** cstdlib и algorithm соответственно